# Accessing Parent thread value from Child thread via inheritableThreadLocal

Tags: java, multithreading, parent-child

While using `childValue()` method in parent thread its throwing an error like `childvalue()` method in Inherited `threadLocal` is not visible. Is there any possible ways to create a child and to access property of parent?

Comment: could you please edit some code regarding your requirement ?

Comment: The method childValue(T) from the type InheritableThreadLocal<WebDriver> is not visible

Comment: public void setDriverThread(WebDriver driverTh) {
 this .driverThread.childValue(driverTh);
  this.driverThread.set(driverTh);
  
 }

Comment: you should use super not this

Comment: can you tell exact syntax Mathan

Comment: this .driverThread.super.childValue(driverTh); //can i use this?